# How can we make ui:inputselect in lightning to dynamically get values from an object's picklist options?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist

I have a requirement to create a Lightning component that contains a ui:inputselect tag which will automatically fetch out its options from a custom pick list of an Object. How can this be achieved?

Comment: yes. at apex controller use describe call to get all the picklist label and value.. and return to lightning. And based on those values prepare picklist in lightning

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should create schema for the picklist and call this method from component using aura init. this will fetch picklist value on loading the component.

```
public static List<String> getLeadStatus(){
List<String> options = new List<String>();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = lead.status.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
    options.add(f.getLabel());
}

return options;}
```

Java script controller code -

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getLeadStatus");
    var inputsel = component.find("InputSelectDynamic");
    var opts=[];
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
            opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
        }
        inputsel.set("v.options", opts);

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

For picklist -

```
<ui:inputSelect label="Status" class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" value="{!v.leadObj.Status}" required="true"/>
```

Comment: But it is not showing options

Comment: Can you please post your code??

Comment: Thank you so much @Ajay , it was very helpful for me to understand the flow.

Comment: Any chance the dynamic could work for more than one picklist ? I am getting the data successfully from apex but .set("v.options", opts); is the same and it overwrites the previous Picklist.

Comment: @Ajay: Could you please add clarity on how the "options" attribute is defined? Is it as <aura:attribute name=options type=[]/>   ??

Comment: @user28452 Use <aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]" description="options" />

Comment: Thanks. That helped. One final question. On the push what does this "class": "optionClass", doing to the array?

Comment: @user28452 you can do that without adding the class attribute. I was adding class attribute dynamically. You can ignore that.